# TCP socket management using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, socket, tcp, multiprocessing

I wrote a Python code for a device that generates an hotspot and communicates with an app using a TCP socket. The communication is managed by a process that opens a socket and uses two threads to send and receive data. The data is shared with the main process using two queues. An additional queue allows the main process to send some commands (e.g. close the communication). The socket process must be able to reopen the socket in case the client closes it. It may be worth to mention that the devices sends data to the client app continuously, while the client sends data occasionally.

The following is the code for the socket process. It seems to work fine but I would like to know if there is some optimization that I could work on.

```
import signal
from multiprocessing import Process
import select
import traceback

class TX_thread (Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, tx_queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = conn
        self.tx_queue = tx_queue
        self.alive = True
        self.connected = True
        print("Socket manager - TX thread started") 

    def quit(self):
        print("TX thread - quit")
        self.alive = False

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            time.sleep(0.05)

            if not self.tx_queue.empty():           
                data = self.tx_queue.get()          
    
                try:                    
                    self.conn.sendall(data.encode())
                except(BrokenPipeError):
                    print("TX - BROKEN PIPE - connection lost")
                    self.connected = False

                except(Exception) as e:
                    traceback.print_exc()


        print("TX thread - exiting...")

class RX_thread (Thread):
    def __init__(self, conn, rx_queue):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.conn = conn
        self.rx_queue = rx_queue
        self.alive = True
        print("Socket manager - RX thread started") 

    def quit(self):
        print("RX thread - quit")
        self.alive = False

    def run(self):

        while self.alive:
            time.sleep(0.05) 

            try:
                readable,_,_ = select.select([self.conn], [], [], 1)

                if readable:
                    data = self.conn.recv(4096)
                    data = data.decode()

                    if data:
                        self.rx_queue.put(data)
            except(Exception) as e:
                traceback.print_exc()    

        print("RX thread - exiting...")
            

class GracefulKiller:
    kill_now = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self, *args):
        self.kill_now = True



class SocketManagerProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, port, rx_queue, tx_queue, control_queue):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.port = port
        self.rx_queue = rx_queue
        self.tx_queue = tx_queue    
        self.control_queue = control_queue
        self.ip = '0.0.0.0'     
        self.killer = GracefulKiller()

    def close_all(self):
        print("Socket manager - close all")
        self.rx_thread.quit()
        self.tx_thread.quit()
        self.tx_thread.join()
        self.rx_thread.join()
        self.conn.close()
        self.s.close()
        self.connected = False

    def setup(self):
        print("Socket manager - starting socket...")
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.s.setblocking(False)   
        self.s.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.s.listen()

        self.connected = False

        while not self.connected:
            time.sleep(.05)
            try:
                self.conn, self.addr = self.s.accept()
                self.connected = True
                print("Socket manager - Connected by ", self.addr)
            except(BlockingIOError):
                pass

        self.tx_thread = TX_thread(self.conn, self.tx_queue)
        self.rx_thread = RX_thread(self.conn, self.rx_queue)

        self.tx_thread.start()      
        self.rx_thread.start()

    def run(self):

        self.setup()            
    
        while not self.killer.kill_now:
                        
            time.sleep(0.5)
            # check connection
            
            if not self.tx_thread.connected:
                print("Socket manager - BROKEN PIPE - connection lost")
                self.close_all()
                print("Reconnecting...")
                self.setup()        
            

            # check control queue
            if not self.control_queue.empty():
                command = self.control_queue.get()
                if command == 'close_all':
                    self.close_all()
                elif command == 'reconnect':
                    self.setup()
            

        print("Socket manager - killing threads...")
        self.close_all()
        print("Socket manager - exited")
                    
            


    if __name__=='__main__':      
        self.output_socket_queue = Queue(1)#deque(maxlen=1)
        self.input_socket_queue = Queue(1)      
        self.socket_control_queue = Queue(1)
        self.socket_manager_process = SocketManagerProcess(9997, 
                                                       self.input_socket_queue, 
                                                       self.output_socket_queue, 
                                                       self.socket_control_queue)
        self.socket_manager_process.start()
```